# Block phone useage on a Windows Mobile 5 device

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0, handhelddevice

I am developing a Windows Mobile app that my company is providing the devices for.  We do not want our users to use the phone that is part of the windows mobile device.

Does anyone know a way to block phone usage?

If it matters, the device type is a Symbol MC-70.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I could come up with was to use the Telphony api provided at:http://tapi.codeplex.com/

It has a CellularLineMonitor class that allows me to hang up on any call after it is made or received.

Answer (score 1):

If your company is providing the devices and you do not want users to use the phone, you should get a data-only plan from your provider.  This will save your company money and ensure that the phone cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  We use a cellular connection to get to the internet (GRPS).  I don't know if we can disable the phone part of our contract with Version or not.  I will try and find out.